# AnyGantt - Transform Scaling and hover/selection

Tags: anychart

I've been using AnyGantt for some time now but I just notice that I had an issue with container scaling and the over/select functions from AnyGantt.

As soon as you're applying a scaling on the container, the hover / select / tooltip is off and don't reflect what's the move is really hovering.

I'm currently using AnyGantt v8.7.1.1930 (2019-12-17).

I created a fork of one sample to showcase the issue on https://playground.anychart.com/wtM5Nmhh/1

Do I have anyway of fixing that issue? Is it something I've done wrong?

Thanks for the insights!

Answer (score 0):

Transform property doesn't affect (doesn't lead to recalculation) cursor coordinates in browser events. It means that the container is scaled, but coordinates in the event context remain the same. There's no workaround for that. We highly do not recommend using transform/scale property for positioning chart containers. If you need to implement show/hide animation, the final scaling factor should equal to 1.